# Where do I place my non-model classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Where should I put my simple classes that are not models (they don't represent any data) and provides only some functionality?**

Like for example:

```
class FileUploader

  def save_uploaded_file(filename, tempfile)
    path = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', filename)
    File.open(path, 'wb+') do |file|
      file.write(tempfile.read)
    end
  end
end
```

What this does is just simply copies file to predefined place.

Do I must to place this under `models`? Or do Rails have some other location more suitable for those kind of classes? I tried to put in `lib` before, but it was just too much of the pain as Rails cached those files inside `lib` directory (edited config to not cache files, but it still cached inside `lib`).

So, I placed those files in `models` but testing becomes very painful (I'm just starting Rails, maybe I'm doing something wrong with the tests) as rake spits out errors about not having set up a test database (I want to test classes that are not related to database in any form or shape - why do I need to set up a database?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For service-type objects I put them in app/services.

For model-type objects I put them in app/models. I do not think it is necessary to inherit from ActiveRecord to be considered a model.

I think your object classifies as a 'service object' since it is designed to wrap the service of uploading a file, it isn't really a domain object like a model would be.

Answer (score 5):

I've taken to adding `app/lib` to some of my projects to accommodate this, but there's also the new Rails 4 `concerns` locations like `app/models/concerns` or `app/controllers/concerns` depending on where this sort of thing is used.

You're right that it's best to avoid putting non-model classes in `app/models`.